# How to permute bits in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have written the following code to permute bits using Python code:

```
iptable=[56,48,40,32,24,16,8,0,57,49, 41,33,25,17,9,1, 58, 50, 42, 34, 26,
     18, 10,  2, 59, 51, 43, 35,
     62, 54, 46, 38, 30, 22, 14,
      6, 61, 53, 45, 37, 29, 21,
     13,  5, 60, 52, 44, 36, 28,
     20, 12,  4, 27, 19, 11, 3]
msg= b'AABBCCDD'
enc = ''
i = 0
while i <= 63:
    x = iptable[i]
    enc = enc + msg[x]
    i = i + 1
print(enc)
```

It returned

```
  enc = enc + msg[x]
IndexError: index out of range
```

So where is the error? And does each character in the msg variable converts to 8 bits or bigger, less?

Comment: Look at what x is. The first time through the loop, you're trying to index 'AABBCCDD'[56]. This... isn't what you meant, surely. (Not an answer, since I have no idea what you're actually trying to do here.)

Comment: And once you've solved that: your `iptable` only has 56 elements, but `i` can be bigger than that. So you'll get errors for lookups in `iptable` too, I expect.

Comment: I am trying to build an encrypted text from msg using permutation from the iptable list.

Comment: @alko: I vote to reopen. OP wants to permute bits in `msg` using `iptable` index permutation e.g., 56-th (zero-based) bit from `msg` should go to `0`-th bit in the result (`enc`), `48`-th bit from `msg` should go to `1`-th bit in `enc`, `40` -> `2`, `32` -> `3`, etc. To get `msg` bits using only stdlib: `bin(int.from_bytes(msg, byteorder='big'))[2:]`. Question is answerable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are quite a few issues in your approach

1. You are using the wrong tool for your trade. You should probably be looking for [bitarray](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/bitarray/)
2. Length of iptable (56) does not conform to the length of iteration (64)

A sample  corrected code using bitarray might look as follows

```
>>> iptable=[56,48,40,32,24,16,8,0,57,49, 41,33,25,17,9,1, 58, 50, 42, 34, 26,
     18, 10,  2, 59, 51, 43, 35,
     62, 54, 46, 38, 30, 22, 14,
      6, 61, 53, 45, 37, 29, 21,
     13,  5, 60, 52, 44, 36, 28,
     20, 12,  4, 27, 19, 11, 3]
>>> from bitarray import bitarray
>>> msg = bitarray(endian='little')
>>> msg.frombytes('AABBCCDD')
>>> enc = bitarray(endian='little')
>>> for i in iptable:
    enc.append(msg[i])


>>> enc
bitarray('00110011001111001100000000001111111100000000000000000000')
>>> msg
bitarray('1000001010000010010000100100001011000010110000100010001000100010')
```

Comment: Your answer is very helpful. I am trying to install bitarray on Linux. It gave me the following error in the terminal: "bitarray/_bitarray.c:9:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
 #include "Python.h"
                    ^
compilation terminated.
error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1"     When I install it I need to find out the number of bits for each character, they are eight, right?

Comment: I managed to install it. The code returns "byte string expected".

Comment: I was able to run the code with no problems after adding b in "msg.frombytes(b'AABBCCDD').

Comment: the bits seems to be wrong e.g., `msg` should end with `1000100` (ascii 'D').

Comment: Accepted, I am just new here!

Answer (score 0):

You could permute bits by converting the message into an integer:

```
def tobin(n):
    return bin(n)[2:].zfill(len(msg)*8)

msgint = int.from_bytes(msg, byteorder='big')
print(tobin(msgint))
print(msgint.to_bytes(len(msg), byteorder='big', signed=False))
# -> 0100000101000001010000100100001001000011010000110100010001000100
# -> b'AABBCCDD'
```

Then you could perfrom bit manipulations directly:

```
result = 0
for i, j in enumerate(iptable):
    if msgint & (1 << j):  # if j-th bit set in msg
        result |= (1 << i) # set i-th bit in the result

print(tobin(result))
print(result.to_bytes(len(msg), byteorder='big', signed=False))
# -> 0000000000000000000000000000111111110000110000000011110000110011
# -> b'\x00\x00\x00\x0f\xf0\xc0<3'
```